# Javascript broken after moving from IE8 to IE11: "Object doesn't support property or method 'all' "

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I was just forced into a browser upgrade (IE8 to IE11) while in the middle of testing. I've lost some essential functionality with some javascript that suddenly doesn't work in my .NET site.

This section of the code was written when I was in grade school, so I'm not extremely familiar with it, but what seems to be the problem is a call to `form.all`. I have to assume that call was built into javascript at some point - there's no definition for it in the code.

There are 7 "if statements" that use `form.all` and they are all written the same way:

```
if(form.all(cTag + "PersonNum") != null)
      form.all(cTag + "PersonNum").value = personNumber;
```

The error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'all'
```

In newer versions of JavaScript, is there a version of `form.all` that performs the same action? All I really need is for someone to point me in the right direction.

*A weird note: the same JavaScript code IS working in production on IE11*

**EDIT** Ok, I found a line that was minimized. It looks like form is a created variable.

```
var form = document.forms(0);
```

**EDIT2** Compatibility view/mode was the solution after all. I had added our production site's domain to the compatibility list and didn't think about it; adding 'localhost' fixed the issue. You just have to set it to the right domain first for it to work :)

Comment: About your weird note, maybe that IE11 browser is running in compatibility mode.

Comment: Can't find documentation on `form.all`, is it a DOM selector function?

Comment: Do you have multiple `<form>` tags on your page?

Comment: I am running compatibility view, I have to for another of our sites on the same domain. No change when I remove it.

Comment: Rick S, thanks for pointing that out, see my edit in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the browser compatability mode when your running in production it's probally on IE8.

You can use obj.getElementsByTagName("*")

You could also add an All method to the prototype if it's not there.

Comment: I just fixed it by adding 'localhost' to the list for compatibility view. I had just set it to our production domain without thinking. I feel ridiculous, but this is the first time I've had to do anything with compatibility mode.

Comment: It's all good, when IE9 came out I had to fix my app. Your better off to get rid of .all. Your better off to use something like jquery but thats just my opinion...glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

IE introduced an [*all* property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx) for certain DOM objects (e.g. *document*) but it was never part of any W3C standard. It allowed access to DOM objects by name or ID using:

```
var element = document(elementNameOrID);
```

or

```
var element = document[elementNameOrID];
```

that is, it is a property that could use the same syntax as a method. Neat. Some other browsers supported it for compatibility, but it pretty much went out of use with IE 6 (not sure when IE started supporting getElementById, I think it was IE 5). But IE continued to think name and ID attributes were the same thing [until IE 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx) in standards mode.

Support for *all* has been dropped from IE 11 [*in standards mode*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#legacyAPIs).

If *form* is a reference to a form element, and `cTag + "PersonNum"` is the name of a form control, then the simplest fix is to change:

```
form.all(cTag + "PersonNum").value
```

to

```
form[cTag + "PersonNum"].value
```

which takes advantage of named form controls being made properties of the form that contains them. This behaviour is standardised and supported by browsers from the very beginning (i.e. every where) and is future proof (it's not going to change).